# Elasticsearch query with filter take more time than query without filter. Why?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using Elasticsearch Version (7.6.1)

Query with Filter is

```
GET mark13/_search
{
    "explain": false,
    "from": 0,
    "size": 500,
    "track_scores": true,
    "stored_fields": [
        "_source"
    ],
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "id": "sorting_algo",
                "params": {
                    "query": "abhinav keshri"
                }
            },
            "order": "desc"
        }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "poca_score": {
            "script": {
                "id": "field",
                "params": {
                    "query": "abhinav keshri"
                }
            }
        }
    },

    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "class" : "42"
                }
              }

            ], 
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "applied_for": {
                            "query": "abhinav keshri",
                            "boost": 118,
                            "fuzziness": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
...
...
...
```

Output of the above query is

```
{
  "took" : 45414,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 4730.905,
    "hits" : [
      {
...
...
...
```

**It took 45414 ms to execute.**

Query without Filter is

```
GET mark13/_search
{
    "explain": false,
    "from": 0,
    "size": 500,
    "track_scores": true,
    "stored_fields": [
        "_source"
    ],
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "id": "sorting_algo",
                "params": {
                    "query": "abhinav keshri"
                }
            },
            "order": "desc"
        }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "poca_score": {
            "script": {
                "id": "script",
                "params": {
                    "query": "abhinav keshri"
                }
            }
        }
    },

    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "applied_for": {
                            "query": "abhinav keshri",
                            "boost": 118,
                            "fuzziness": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
...
...
...
```

Output of the above query is

```
{
  "took" : 7104,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 9920,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 4730.905,
    "hits" : [
      {
```

**It took 7104 ms to execute.**

My Expectation was that , Filter query would take less time as compared to non-Filter query, since there is less results to apply bool query on.

Also i have tried to execute filter query in different formats (one given above)-

also i have tried following format. (it gives me the same results ).

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50,
    "track_scores": true,
    "stored_fields": [
        "_source"
    ],
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "id": "sorting_algo",
                "params": {
                    "query": "abhinav keshri"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "poca_score": {
            "script": {
                "id": "script",
                "params": {
                    "query": "abhinav keshri"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [

            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                ...
                                ...
                            }
                        ],
                        "must": {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    {
                                        "terms": {
                                            "class": [
                                                "42"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    ...
                                    ...

                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Question **Why Filter query take longer than non-Filter query?**

Comment: see of this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/62164052/11935734

Comment: @PrernaGupta, I took a look at the link you provided. I want to give you the configuration of my ES server .  RAM(23 gb) CPU cores( 6) NODE ( 1) .

Comment: There are 42,00,000 documents in the Index

Comment: 1 shard  and NO Replica (as you might have already guessed).

Comment: How much JVM is given to ES process and do you see spike in memory usage when you hit the query

Comment: Previously i had given JVM heap memory of (-Xms1g) 1GB. But even after changing it to (-Xms10g) it didn't help. Same time difference is there. 7sec (without filter) 50sec(with filter)

Comment: ok, and do you see spike in memory usage

Comment: Yes, it is occuppying 10gb now , earlier (it was at 2.3gb)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215645/discussion-between-abhinav-keshri-and-prerna-gupta).

Comment: What is weird is that the query with filter returns more documents than without. It would be nice to run both queries through the [profiler](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html) and see the output of both... Can you add `"profile": true` to both queries and share the output?

Comment: @Val Here are the Profile Output you asked. ( https://pastebin.com/bP5nhSuz ) query without Filter. ( https://pastebin.com/f23h2CVK ) query with Filter. Query is Exactly the same as asked in the Question. I have removed some **description** and **hits** and some other replacements . Without touching the time information. Because it contained some confidential information.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you also provide the execution plan of both queries by adding `"explain": true` to both queries, please?

Comment: @Val Here is the Explanation. Sorry for being late. I have obfuscated the data ( https://pastebin.com/BiJvyfq5 ).

Comment: Thank you! Which one of the queries did you explain?

Comment: @Val Explanation for Query without filter (https://pastebin.com/gGgxxenh). Explanation for Query with Filter ( https://pastebin.com/bX2ZD8rn). Thank you

Comment: did you experiment with `track_scores` option? It can be some conflict between filter that, actually, ignores scoring, and tracking score with sorting. Interesting to test with setting this option to false.

Comment: 1st of All ) I need track score. 
2nd) It did not make significant difference to make track_scores false. (order of milliseconds difference)